# Correct structure of RNA

Tags: rna, rna-sequencing

Of the 2 figures, which is the correct structure of RNA,

This is the link :  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYgyv.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYgyv.jpg[image]

Sorry, the figure is not to scale.

If there's any problem with the question please inform me.

Comment: Homework questions are off-topic on Biology unless you have shown your attempt at an answer. For more information see our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). It is also bad practice to have figures as part of the question as they are inaccessible to partially sighted people. In addition the figures are incomprehensible and neither represents RNA.

Answer (score 3):

Both figures include A,G,T,C.

Those are abbreviations for the bases adenine, guanine, thymine and cytosine.

RNA does not contain thymine, but its unmethylated form uracil, abbreviated with an U.

Thus, none of the structures represents RNA.

Comment: Please do not answer homework questions where the poster has made no attempt to research the question himself.

Answer (score 1):

As Marzipanherz said, RNA does not contain thymine. Furthermore, none of those resemble any kind of RNA structure you usually see, for example two dimensional secondary structures showing watson-crick basepairing such as this example:
http://www.rna-seqblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/secondary1.jpg

Familiarize yourself with RNA by e.g. reading the wikipedia article or something https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA
After you've done this, you can e.g. go to the vienna webserver http://rna.tbi.univie.ac.at/cgi-bin/RNAWebSuite/RNAfold.cgi and predict secondary structures of your own RNA sequences.

Comment: Please do not answer homework questions where the poster has made no attempt to research the question himself.